# Is Files.lines().allMatch() ordered?

Tags: java, stream

I'm trying to get away from `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`, but the limitations of streams are proving to be hard to overcome in an elegant way in this case. I want the first line which matches a certain criterion and the last two lines before this which matches two different criteria. This seems to be the best I can do, but it only works if lines are encountered in the right order so it doesn't terminate early. So are they? It's hard to tell from the documentation.

```
String[] savedLines = { "", "", "" };
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
    lines.allMatch(line -> {
        if (line.startsWith(s1)) {
            savedLines[0] = line;
        else if (line.startsWith(s2) && line.contains(s3)) {
            savedLines[1] = line;
        } else if (line.startsWith(s4)) {
            savedLines[2] = line;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: You can get a `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Path)`, but the downside is this method does not stream, it loads everything into your RAM, which makes is unusable for very large files. As far as I know, the lines are then ordered, first line is the first entry in the resulting list.

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect what you are saying. Can you show how you would do it with the `while` approach?

Comment: @magicmn I accidentally described a different but similar loop. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the lines are being read from a file, I can't see why they wouldn't be in file order - it would take more storage to do anything other than read the current line, then read the next line etc.

Irrespective, don't do it like this: you are going against [what it says in the documentation about the predicate of `Stream.allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)):

> `predicate` - a non-interfering, stateless predicate to apply to elements of this stream

Your predicate is not stateless. You shouldn't do this in `allMatch`.

Stick with `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I found a different solution: `for (String line : (Iterable<String>)lines::iterator)`.

Comment: In general, don't rely on using a Stream in this way: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/StreamToIterable

Comment: It works just fine inserted directly into a for-each.